# How can I convert a large string to integer in java?

Tags: java, string, hex, biginteger, parseint

Given the following string:

```
3132333435363738396162636465666768696a6b6c6d6e6f70
```

I converted the string to hex and now i want to file write it as hex not a string. I tried converting it to int but `Integer.parseInt` converts up to 4 only and if go beyond that it would give error already.

Comment: What does this have to do with swing?

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried the [`BigInteger` constructor taking a string and a radix](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)?

```
BigInteger value = new BigInteger(hex, 16);
```

Sample code:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hex = "3132333435363738396162636465666768696a6b6c6d6e6f70";
        BigInteger number = new BigInteger(hex , 16);
        System.out.println(number); // As decimal...
    }
}
```

Output:

```
308808885829455478403317837970537433512288994552567292653424
```

Comment: i need to file write it as is.

Comment: @user2090151: I have no idea what you mean by that. It's a number - there's no such thing as "as is". You need to represent it somehow - as a decimal number or whatever. You asked how to parse it as a number - I've shown you how to do that. If you just want to parse the hex string into a *byte* array, that's a completely different matter, and you should have asked that to start with. (Don't ask a new question - there are *lots* of hex parsing questions on Stack Overflow.)

Comment: after convert, its value is changing how to get same value?

Comment: @AmitSharma: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're asking. I suggest you ask a new question, with a complete example including what you expect to see and what you actually see.

Comment: i convert this value "104917385788526078598" and i am getting after convert this value"1230498387628795168785816"

Comment: @AmitSharma: Again: "I suggest you ask a new question, with a complete example including what you expect to see and what you actually see." (Explain what that value is meant to represent, too... is it actually a hex number? And you want it back as hex again later? Do *not* reply to this comment with answers to those questions - include the details in your new question.)

Answer (score 1):

Use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), one of the constructors takes a radix.

```
BigInteger value = new BigInteger(hexString, 16);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
new BigInteger("3132333435363738396162636465666768696a6b6c6d6e6f70", 16)
```